# How to perform a running count on null values that resets on non-null values

Tags: sql, count, amazon-redshift, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

I am trying to calculate a column that performs a running count of consecutive null values, but the running count will reset upon non-null values.

I am currently trying to achieve this on this version of redshift:

PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.8187

I tried using this window function but this is just continuously incrementing the number for each null.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, VAL ORDER BY VAL ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

For example if I had a dataset like this:

```
id  | date  | val
----+-------+-------
  1 |   1/1 | NULL
  1 |   1/2 | NULL 
  1 |   1/3 | NULL 
  1 |   1/4 |  1
  1 |   1/5 | NULL 
  1 |   1/6 | NULL 
  1 |   1/7 |  1 
  2 |   1/8 |  2
  2 |   1/9 | NULL
  2 |   1/1 | NULL
  2 |   1/2 |  1
  2 |   1/3 | NULL
  2 |   1/4 |  0
  2 |   1/5 | NULL
  2 |   1/6 | NULL
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
id  | date  | val   | foo
----+-------+-------+-------
  1 |   1/1 | NULL  |  1
  1 |   1/2 | NULL  |  2
  1 |   1/3 | NULL  |  3
  1 |   1/4 |  1    |
  1 |   1/5 | NULL  |  1 
  1 |   1/6 | NULL  |  2
  1 |   1/7 |  1    |
  2 |   1/8 |  2    |
  2 |   1/9 | NULL  |  1
  2 |   1/1 | NULL  |  2
  2 |   1/2 |  1    |
  2 |   1/3 | NULL  |  1
  2 |   1/4 |  0    |
  2 |   1/5 | NULL  |  1
  2 |   1/6 | NULL  |  2
```

Comment: what is your complete SQL?

Comment: Is this mock up data? The data you have provided do not provide enough distinct values for running sum to generate your output, you could get only running sum with id, val combo with above example data

Comment: This is indeed mockup data. I do have additional fields in my datasets but theyre all transactional figures and I do not know if they could be used as partitions ie LTV, spend velocity etc.

Comment: I played it little bit and came up with running sums for id, val combo. The sum column goes like this 1,2,3,0,4,5,0,1,0,2... because it's not possible IMO to create the output with above input. Used `sum(case when val = 'NULL' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id,val order by id,val,date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as foo`

Comment: That is good to know. What additional things would be needed to make the above output possible?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your actual data, probably additional columns or different set of columns for `partition by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**Starter**

I think that there is a glitch in your sample data, in the below highlighted records:

```
id  | date  | val   | foo
----+-------+-------+-------
  1 |   1/1 | NULL  |  1
  1 |   1/2 | NULL  |  2
  1 |   1/3 | NULL  |  3
  1 |   1/4 |  1    |
  1 |   1/5 | NULL  |  1 
  1 |   1/6 | NULL  |  2
  1 |   1/7 |  1    |
  2 |   1/8 |  2    |       --> this record is not in sequence
  2 |   1/9 | NULL  |  1    --> neither this one
  2 |   1/1 | NULL  |  2    --> so this record should have foo = 1, not 2
  2 |   1/2 |  1    |
  2 |   1/3 | NULL  |  1
  2 |   1/4 |  0    |
  2 |   1/5 | NULL  |  1
  2 |   1/6 | NULL  |  2
```

I simply expurged these three records from the dataset. If you are not ok with that, do not read further...

---

**Answer**

This is a variation of the gaps-and-island problem. To solve it, the idea is to build groups made of consecutive null records. For this, we compute `row_number()`s over two different partitions (by `id` vs by `id` *and* null/not null `val`). The difference between the row numbers defines the group.

Then, all that is left to do is assign new row numbers to each record having a null `val` within the group it belongs to.

Query:

```
select 
    id,
    date,
    val,
    case when val is null
        then row_number() over(partition by id, rn1 - rn2 order by date) 
        else null
    end foo
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() 
            over(order by id, date) rn1,
        row_number() 
            over(partition by id, case when val is null then 1 else 0 end order by date ) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
order by id, date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qrn4TmqxXNfXx9nwBZtKte/0)**:

```
| id  | date                     | val | foo |
| --- | ------------------------ | --- | --- |
| 1   | 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |     | 1   |
| 1   | 2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z |     | 2   |
| 1   | 2019-01-03T00:00:00.000Z |     | 3   |
| 1   | 2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z | 1   |     |
| 1   | 2019-01-05T00:00:00.000Z |     | 1   |
| 1   | 2019-01-06T00:00:00.000Z |     | 2   |
| 1   | 2019-01-07T00:00:00.000Z | 1   |     |
| 2   | 2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1   |     |
| 2   | 2019-01-03T00:00:00.000Z |     | 1   |
| 2   | 2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z | 0   |     |
| 2   | 2019-01-05T00:00:00.000Z |     | 1   |
| 2   | 2019-01-06T00:00:00.000Z |     | 2   |
```